# How to handle a non-resolvable parent POM?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I've found quite a lot questions regarding this.  None of which seemed to help.

I have some old code using Eclipse SWT V4234 that I'm trying to resurrect.  I have cloned the repo with git and imported it into Eclipse IDE.

```xml
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipse-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

  <groupId>eclipse.platform.swt</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipse.platform.swt</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules> 
     <module>bundles/org.eclipse.swt</module>
```

This resulted in this error :

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
> eclipse.platform.swt:eclipse.platform.swt:3.8.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not
> find artifact org.eclipse:eclipse-parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and
> 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

What I need to understand is what the "Parent" attribute is attempting to achieve.  My assumption (maybe incorrectly) was I had cloned SWT as a standalone project without dependence to any parent.

If I comment out the parent attribute, the issue disappears, but as I have little knowledge on Maven and Java development this made me ask why this was required in the first place.

So what is the relationship between groupId/artifactId (eclipse.platform.swt) and the Parent groupId/artifactId (org.eclipse).

So what is org.eclipse and why does it need to be mentioned? Is it fine they overlap?

Do I need to reference the parent POM if I'm making a standalone package for SWT?

Is it safe just to comment out the parent attribute?

Comment: The SWT Git repository is not self-contained by referring [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/pom.xml?id=9449ba9dd30ee45e14aaac44bd81bd719fd58a0d#n21) to the [Eclipse platform parent POM that is contained in a different Git repository](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git/tree/eclipse-platform-parent/pom.xml). The parent POM contains common configurations, e.g. to use the Maven plugin Tycho since Maven cannot resolve OSGi dependencies and cannot build Eclipse plugins by default without Tycho. So comment out wouldn't work.

Comment: See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html